# Shared group directory with individual user files

Tags: permissions, groups

I have a mounted NFS partition in which a specific group, say `nfsgroup`, has `rwx` for the directory (call it `nfsdir`). If my user `brian` is a member of `nfsgroup` and creates a file in `nfsdir`, then I chgrp it to say `brian` (my own group), other users in the `nfsgroup` can still delete my file. It gives me the `rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘test.txt’?` prompt, but still lets me delete the file from another user not part of the `brian` group but a part of the `nfsgroup`.

Is there a way such that I can allow all users in `nfsgroup` to create files in `nfsdir`, but also provide a way for members of `nfsgroup` to protect individual files from other group members modifying them?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Inside `nfsgroup` I made my own directory `brian_private` and then did `chmod 744 brian_private`. Now all files in `brian_private` are only modifiable by me.